# How to load data in ionic slide box with the help of u i-view in another slide?

Tags: angularjs

I want to load the data as soon as I slide. I am using `ionic-slidebox` like,

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" active-slide="1" show-pager="false">    
        <ion-slide  disable-scroll="false">
            <ion-scroll>
               <div> loading some data</div>
            </ion-scroll>  
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

on-slide-changed I am calling slide Has Changed()function and doing state.go() I am getting the slider effect but because of the empty slide in code I am getting the empty slide

I have to load the data in the empty slide. I have tried by placing the ng-controller and loading the template in the empty slide

Comment: what is that data going to alike ? You can update your scope object on slidehaschanged function call and bind to your html.

Comment: the above mentioned code is in one state, and in on-slide-change iam idoing state.go("to that state")want to load another state data in empty slide

Comment: i want to change the state on slide change